# How to use the CADO-NFS to calculate DLP in GF(p^2)?

Tags: discrete-logarithm

I have question regarding DLP in GF(p^m)
I know we can use CADO-NFS to solve the DLP in GF(p).
But what if we move into the GF(p^m) and are working with polynomials? Does the Cado tools can calculate it still? If so, how to use it when the domain is GF(P^2) with polynomials?

Anyone with some experience with this tool could help me, please? I didn't find anything on the Internet and the documentation that came with CADO say anything about it
Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: CADO-NFS is An Implementation of the Number Field Sieve Algorithm. That is for factoring integers not for discrete log. Where did you see that?

Comment: CADO-NFS _can_ compute discrete logs, in fact it was used to set the latest records on it. Anyway, this question is the same as [this one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/100021/how-can-i-use-mov-algorithm-to-solve-this-problem). Was this a CTF problem or something?